# Decorator pattern in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, decorator

Can someone give me an example of the Decorator design pattern in C++ ? 
I have come across the Java version of it, but found it difficult to understand the C++ version of it (from the examples I found).

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Vince Huston Design Patterns, even though its layout is poor, has C++ implementation for most design patterns in the Gang of Four book.

Click for [Decorator](http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/decorator.html).

There isn't much difference with Java, except the manual memory handling that you'd better wrap with smart pointers :)

Comment: +1 for this website.I always refer to this for cpp implementation.I also think that the messy memory management is the reason you don't see this pattern much in cpp.

Comment: I don't always refer to the implementation, but I appreciate not being spammed by ads and the advices on when to apply, when not to and what it brings in comparison to other related patterns.

Answer (score 11):

I've found the website [Sourcemaking](http://sourcemaking.com/) to be a pretty good one when it comes to [explaining different Design Patterns](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns).

The [Decorator](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator) design pattern has C++ examples, such as an [overview example](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator/cpp/2), a "[before and after](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator/cpp/1)", and an [example with packet encoding/decoding](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator/cpp/3).

Comment: +1 for the great answer. I checked the second example provided there (https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator/cpp/2) - isn't it missing a virtual destructor in the interface class (the Widget class) ?

Comment: @GuyAvraham - thanks.  You are correct, the base class(es) should have virtual destructors as a general "correct practice".  However, in this example, their code will work fine since a) they aren't deleting any objects through a base class pointer (they aren't deleting them at all?!?!?  They are just returning / exiting, **kind of sloppy**...) and b) the constructors of the derived objects' don't allocate any resources / open any files / etc., so technically, not calling their destructors won't cause problems... TODAY.  But you are right -- as the code grows, this could change.  Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Computer
{
public:
    virtual void display()
    {
        cout << "I am a computer..." << endl;
    }
};

class CDDrive : public Computer
{
private:
    Computer* c;
public:
    CDDrive(Computer* _c)
    {
        c = _c;
    }
    void display()
    {
        c->display();
        cout << "with a CD Drive..." << endl;
    }
};

class Printer : public Computer
{
private:
    CDDrive* d;
public:
    Printer(CDDrive* _d)
    {
        d = _d;
    }
    void display()
    {
        d->display();
        cout << "with a printer..." << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Computer* c = new Computer();
    CDDrive* d = new CDDrive(c);
    Printer* p = new Printer(d);

    p->display();
}
```

Comment: this is a nice solution to a different problem, but this is not a "truly" decorator pattern, this design is missing the decorator class that is inherited by any decorator in this case printer and CD drive

Answer (score 0):

[image: c++ decorator pattern, plantuml]

I'm learning c++ and design pattern recently, I'll give an example from <[Head First Design Pattern](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124)>.

the main.cpp is here:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Decaf.h"
#include "Espresso.h"
#include "MochaDecorator.h"
#include "MilkDecorator.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;


int main(){
    cout << "---------------------------" << endl;
   
    // only Decaf, no addsOn
    Beverage* decafOnly = new Decaf();
    cout << decafOnly->getDescription() << endl;
    cout << decafOnly->cost() << endl;
    delete decafOnly;
    cout << "---------------------------" << endl;

    // Decaf + Mocha
    Beverage* decaf = new Decaf();
    MochaDecorator mocha_decaf = MochaDecorator(decaf);
    cout << mocha_decaf.getDescription() << endl;
    cout << mocha_decaf.cost() << endl;
    delete decaf;
    cout << "---------------------------" << endl;

    // Espresso + Milk
    Beverage* espresso = new Espresso();
    MilkDecorator milk_espresso = MilkDecorator(espresso);
    cout << milk_espresso.getDescription() << endl;
    cout << milk_espresso.cost() << endl;
    delete espresso;
    cout << "---------------------------" << endl;

    // Note: decorators can wrap not only components but the other decorators as well

    // Esresso + Mocha + Milk + Milk,  method 1-------------------------------
    // Beverage* espresso2 = new Espresso();                               // Espresso
    // MochaDecorator* mocha_espresso = new MochaDecorator(espresso2);     // Espresso + Mocha
    // MilkDecorator* milk_deco = new MilkDecorator(mocha_espresso);       // Espresso + Mocha + Milk
    // MilkDecorator* milk_deco2 = new MilkDecorator(milk_deco);           // Espresso + Mocha + Milk + Milk
    // cout << milk_deco2->getDescription() << endl;
    // cout << milk_deco2->cost() << endl;
    // delete espresso2;
    // delete mocha_espresso;
    // delete milk_deco;
    // delete milk_deco2;

    // Esresso + Mocha + Milk + Milk,  method 2------------------------------
    Beverage* espresso2 = new MilkDecorator(new MilkDecorator(new MochaDecorator(new Espresso())));
    cout << espresso2->getDescription() << endl;
    cout << espresso2->cost() << endl;
    delete espresso2;
 
    
    cout << "---------------------------" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

other files please see my github:

https://github.com/jwbecalm/Head-First-Design-Patterns-in-CPP/tree/main/ch03_Decorator