# Decorator pattern vs. Call super anti-pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, decorator, anti-patterns

Let's have a simple Decorator example:

```
struct IStuff {
  virtual void Info()=0;
  virtual ~IStuff() { }
};

class Ugly : public IStuff {
public:
  void Info() { cout  << "Ugly"; }
};

class Shiny : public IStuff {
  IStuff* stuff;
public:
  Shiny(IStuff* stuff) {
    this->stuff = stuff;
  }
  ~Shiny() {
    delete stuff;
  }
  void Info() {
    stuff->Info(); // <------------------------------- call super?
    cout << "->Shiny";
  }
};

int main() {
  IStuff* s = new Ugly();
  s = new Shiny(s); // decorate
  s = new Shiny(s); // decorate more
  s->Info(); // Ugly->Shiny->Shiny
  delete s;
  return 0;
}
```

Is this also the [Call super](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_super) anti-pattern?

*Call super is a design pattern in which a particular class stipulates that in a derived subclass, the user is required to override a method and call back the overridden function itself at a particular point.*

Here is a [little different implementation](http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/decorator.html) Is there any difference in design?

Comment: No, it's not call super because you're not calling a super class, you're calling a contained object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not Call super. You call the `Info` method of another `IStuff` instance, not the overriden version.

Call super version:

```
struct IStuff {
  // If you override this, you MUST call the base class version <-- call super
  virtual void Info()
  {
    // a default implementation.

    std::cout << "Super call ";  
  }
  virtual ~IStuff() { }
};

class Shiny : public IStuff {
public:
  void Info() {
    IStuff::Info();  // don't forget to call base implementation.
    std::cout << "->Shiny";
  }
};
```

Some implementations of Decorator are making a super call to a Decorator base class, that is responsible to hold, call and manage the decorated reference:

```
struct IStuff 
{
  virtual void Info() = 0;
  virtual ~IStuff() { }
};

class Stuff : public IStuff
{
public:
    void Info() { std::cout << "Basic stuff"; }
};

class StuffDecorator : public IStuff
{
    IStuff* decorated_;
public:
    StuffDecorator(IStuff* decoratedStuff) :
        decorated_(decoratedStuff) {}
    ~StuffDecorator() { delete decorated_; }

    void Info()
    {
        decorated_->Info();
    }
};

class Shiny : public StuffDecorator 
{
public:
  Shiny(IStuff* stuff) : StuffDecorator(stuff) { }

  void Info() 
  {
    StuffDecorator::Info();
    std::cout << "->Shiny";
  }
};
```

To avoid the super call you might want to combine Decorator with [Template Method](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method):

```
class StuffDecorator : public IStuff
{
    IStuff* decorated_;
public:
    StuffDecorator(IStuff* decoratedStuff) :
        decorated_(decoratedStuff) {}
    ~StuffDecorator() { delete decorated_; }

    void Info()
    {
        decorated_->Info();
        DoInfo();
    }
private:
    // Template method
    virtual void DoInfo() = 0;
};


class Shiny : public StuffDecorator 
{
public:
  Shiny(IStuff* stuff) : StuffDecorator(stuff) { }
private:
  void DoInfo() 
  {
    std::cout << "->Shiny";
  }
};
```

Comment: I get it. I also updated my question with [another implementation](http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/decorator.html) which was accepted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988066/decorator-pattern-in-c) which seems exactly like your call super version - or did I overlook something?

Comment: @JanTuroň You're right. I edited my answer and provided a soultion without Call super.