# Add property value to a down cast struct causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I got this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Base {
  Base(string name) {
    this->name = name;
  }
  string name;
};

struct Derived: Base {
  string name2;
};

template <typename T>
T createNode(string name) {
  Base* node = new Base(name);
  return static_cast<T>(node);
}

int main() {
  Derived* node = createNode<Derived*>("hej");
  node->name2 = "bajs";
  cout << node->name2;
}
```

And the `node->name2 = "bajs";` line causes (random) segmentation fault. I'm just wondering how I can correct this to not cause segmentation fault. I still want to call `createNode()` to create the base node and set all the property members after. Is it doable in `c++`?

Comment: why are you mixing templates and inheritance this way? if `createNode` is a template , then you shouldn't be creating a `new Base` in it. If you want inheritance remove the template and have the method return `Base`

Comment: It is hard to undersatnd why derived class has `string name2;`. Also I think `createNode` should use `T` instead of `Base` in statement `Base* node = new Base(name);`

Comment: You can't just case a pointer to a base object to pointer to derived type and expect it to work. The pointed to object is still a `Base`. It does not have a `name2` member.

Comment: I guess re-reading the text book on C++ is the order of the day

Comment: Saying "poo" in a program is so funny and awesome and really mature.

Comment: This is nearly the same as your previous question... to which I answered that you need to do `new decltype(*T)`, not `new Base`

Comment: @MattMcNabb can you give me an example I tried `new decltype(*T)`. But it gives me `'T' does not refer to a value`?

Comment: sorry, try `decltype(*(T{}))` . This'd be a lot easier if you made your template parameter be the type, instead of the pointer to the type

Comment: @MattMcNabb it stills give me an error `cannot allocate reference type 'decltype(*(Derived *({  })))'`

Comment: just use the type as the template parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, I do not understand the idea of your program, but I think, it have to be like that:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Base {
  Base(string name) {
    this->name = name;
  }
  string name;
};

struct Derived: Base {
    Derived(string name):Base(name)
    {
    }
    // string name2; // it is not needed
};

template <typename T>
T* createNode(string name) {
  T* node = new T(name);
  return node;
}

int main() {
  Derived* node = createNode<Derived>("hej");
  node->name = "bajs";
  cout << node->name;
}
```

Comment: I want the `createNode()` to create the base class and then just add pops to it, because I want my program to be DRY. The base class contains many props that could be inherited by any derived classes.

Comment: @einstein C++ has a type system , once an object is created it cannot change type or add new fields or anything

Comment: @einstein : But in your code, you create element of base class and are trying to use field that is not exist in the base class.

Comment: @VolAnd thanks for the explanation. I just used your example and correct it  to fit my purpose a bit.

Answer (score 2):

This bit of code:

```
template <typename T>
T createNode(string name) {
  Base* node = new Base(name);
  return static_cast<T>(node);
}
```

creates an object of type `Base`.

This:

```
  Derived* node = createNode<Derived*>("hej");
  node->name2 = "najs";    // No need to use rude words, even if you think most people can't read them.
```

Uses the created object as `Derived`. Since `Derived` requires more space than `Base`, when you use `name2`, you are overwriting something outside of the object created in `createNode`. `name2` also hasn't been constructed, meaning the assignment most likely uses random garbage values, which could well in itself cause a crash.

You will need to rearrange your code such that it creates the correct object first, and if you want to use a constructor, you need to have a constructor for `Derived` that takes the named object. [There are some other ways to achieve this too, but typically not what you want here]

Comment: thanks for your explanation. I will user more najser words in the future. But isn't there anyway I can create the base class with a function that sets the base properties and then add properties to this object? My base class contains a lot of properties the could be inherited.

Comment: @einstein Maybe you're looking for the Decorator Pattern?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988066/decorator-pattern-in-c

Comment: Simply put, no. There are various ways that you can "add things" to other other things - the decorator pattern is one, having a container type (`vector`, `map` or similar) inside the class is another. Which is most suitable depends on what you are actually trying to achieve.