# Creating new c++ interfaces over old one to add new functions

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand if there are best practices around than the one below.
So in our project we had created an interface `IForm` like below:

```
class IForm {
 protected:
  IForm() {}

 public:

  virtual ~IForm() {}
  virtual const std::string& GetId() const = 0;
  virtual const std::string& GetTitle() const = 0;
  virtual void SetTitle(const std::string& title) = 0;
  virtual void SetFormError(const std::string& error_text) = 0;
  virtual void ClearFormError() = 0;
};
```

And then the requirement came to have more functions and therefore we created new interface `IForm2`:

```
class IForm2: public IForm {
 protected:
  IForm2() = default;

 public:
  virtual ~IForm2() = default;
  virtual void RemoveWidget(const std::string &id) = 0;
  virtual void Clear() = 0;
};
```

My question is:

Is there a way around this ? Instead of adding new interface, is there some design pattern that I can use to implement newer requirements rather than adding newer interfaces?

I know the above method works fine. I am just looking for alternatives to implement functionalities.

Comment: You could just modify the existing interface.

Comment: Why are you trying to simulate C# design in C++? I very much doubt you'll end up with an efficient design.

Comment: @DeiDei its not C# per say. its one way of programming interfaces. What I am looking for is a better way.

Comment: Btw; this " virtual ~IForm2() = default;" adds nothing useful over what you already got from the base class.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I could but the architect argues that the interfaces are published to other teams so should remain unchanged. And any new functionality must be added in newer interface deriving the old one.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I agree. If we can ignore that :)

Comment: Perhaps "inline namespace"s are what you are looking for??  Maybe read this: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill21.htm

Comment: @Monku If the code is all internal to your organisation, go hit your architect with a clue-by-four and get the other teams to adjust to the new interface ;-) no point keeping legacy crap around or creating technical debt unless it's to please a customer (who's hopefully paying for it). When it's all internal, the code should just be fixed/updated IMHO and then ppl just have to deal with it..

Comment: Why would you need an alternative? It's difficult to answer without knowing what properties should new alternative have.

Answer (score 0):

I've never actually had need of it but you might want to look up the decorator design pattern.

Here's a link to a SO answer about decorators.

[Decorator pattern in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988066/decorator-pattern-in-c)

Comment: if I understand it correctly, decorator pattern does not add functionalities, it makes existing dynamic.

Comment: "In object-oriented programming, the decorator pattern (also known as Wrapper, an alternative naming shared with the Adapter pattern) is a design pattern that allows behavior to be added to an individual object, either statically or dynamically, without affecting the behavior of other objects from the same class." -Wikipedia

So, per the definition, you can add additional functionality.  But, as per the discussion under the question, is this the right thing to do?  Probably not since the upkeep will eventually become over bearing for very little gain.