# Retrieve objects pointers of different type

Tags: c++, c++14, folly

Consider I have a bunch pointers to to different objects of different classes

```
class1* obj1;
class2* obj2;
class3* obj3;
```

and they all have one method `getArray()`  which returns a  vector for post processing.

if all of these pointers are stored in some sort of a list (a list of void pointers say)

while I am iterating the list is there a way to figure what type of a pointer cast can be used?

I understand this can be solved by class hierarchy and deriving the above classes from a single class. Since a lot of it is legacy code can something like what is mentioned be done?

Folly dynamic does not let me store pointers, thats one thing that is tried

Comment: Do all classes implement an interface? If yes, you can cast to the type of the interface. If they are not linked in any form (interface, inheritance) it's not that easy.

Comment: Can you modify the list in question?

Comment: Can we replace the list of `void*` with a list of something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If getArray() always has the same signature (or similar enough to cast to the same type) - what you could do is create a class hierarchy for a [decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988066/decorator-pattern-in-c) of the [duck-typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) legacy objects/classes.   You can use a template derived class of a non-template interface to wrap without too much typing work.

Something along these lines (with more defensive coding, possibly smart pointers to the legacy object, etc. etc.):

```
class IDecorator {
  public:
    virtual std::vector<ubyte> GetArray() = 0;
};

template<typename TLegacyType>
class TDecorator : public IDecorator {
   public:
     TDecorator(const TLegacyType *ip_legacy_object)
       : mp_legacy_object(ip_legacy_object) {}
     std::vector<ubyte> GetArray() override {
        return mp_legacy_object->GetArray();
     }

   private:
     const TLegacyType *mp_legacy_object;        
};
```

Comment: Dynamic allocation and placement new SOO both seem overkill for this problem.  Using vtables implies one or the other.

Comment: Both are great answers, I had to go with Joris' answer to fit in the existing code

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class R, class Op>
struct any_ptr {
  void* ptr=0;
  R(*f)( void* ) = 0;

  R operate() const { return f(ptr); }
  explicit operator bool() const { return ptr; }
  template<class T>
  T* as() const { return static_cast<T*>(ptr); }

  any_ptr(any_ptr const&)=default;
  any_ptr& operator=(any_ptr const&)=default;
  any_ptr()=default;

  template<class T>
  any_ptr(T* p_in):ptr(p_in),
    f( [](void* ptr)->R{ return Op{}( ptr ); } )
  {}
};
```

`any_ptr` supports storing any pointer that supports `Op`, where `Op` is a stateless function object type returning `R`.

```
struct get_array_t{
  template<class T>
  auto operator()(T* t)const{ return t->getArray(); }
};
using any_ptr_get_array = any_ptr< std::vector<int>, get_array_t >;
```

now `any_ptr_get_array` can store a pointer to any type that supports `.getArray()` that returns `vector<int>`.

To call `getArray`:

```
void test(any_ptr_get_array ptr){
  if(ptr){
    auto vec = ptr.operation();
  }
}
```

This technique could be called manual type erasure using a template generated vtable.